# Yii2 prepared statements fail to evaluate parameters wrapped in quotes

Tags: postgresql, pdo, yii2, postgis

```
$params = [
    ':x1' => $locationBox['leftLongitude'],
    ':y1' => $locationBox['topLatitude'],
    ':x2' => $locationBox['rightLongitude'],
    ':y2' => $locationBox['topLatitude'],
    ':x3' => $locationBox['rightLongitude'],
    ':y3' => $locationBox['bottomLatitude'],
    ':x4' => $locationBox['leftLongitude'],
    ':y4' => $locationBox['bottomLatitude'],
    ':x5' => $locationBox['leftLongitude'],
    ':y5' => $locationBox['topLatitude']
];

$sql = "
    ....
    INNER JOIN tag_geo T3 ON (T3.id = T2.tag_id_b AND ST_Covers(ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((:x1 :y1, :x2 :y2, :x3 :y3, :x4 :y4, :x5 :y5))'), T3.geo_location));
";

$connection = \Yii::$app->getDb();
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindValues($params);
$result = $command->queryAll();
```

I get an error:
**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :x1 Failed to prepare SQL**

Notice single tick ('POLYGON), if I remove the ticks that wrap the POLYGON function the parameters get evaluated but another error occurred, since this POLYGON must be in single  quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the single quotes around `POLYGON` function, the polygon part is recognized by the db engine as it is, e.g. as the string `POLYGON((:x1 :y1, :x2 :y2, :x3 :y3, :x4 :y4, :x5 :y5))`. So you should implement only one marker (`:polygon`) in the sql statement istead:

```
<?php

$sql = "
    ....
    INNER JOIN tag_geo T3 ON (T3.id = T2.tag_id_b AND ST_Covers(ST_GeogFromText(:polygon), T3.geo_location));
";

$params = [
    ":poligon" => sprintf( // Output: POLYGON((x1-value y1-value, x2-value y2-value, ...))
            "POLYGON((%s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s))"
            , $locationBox['leftLongitude']
            , $locationBox['topLatitude']
            , $locationBox['rightLongitude']
            , $locationBox['topLatitude']
            , $locationBox['rightLongitude']
            , $locationBox['bottomLatitude']
            , $locationBox['leftLongitude']
            , $locationBox['bottomLatitude']
            , $locationBox['leftLongitude']
            , $locationBox['topLatitude']
    )
];

//...
```

Of course, if it still doesn't work use question mark markers (`?`) instead.

This situation is similar with the one where one tries to prepare an sql statement which uses the `LIKE` keyword. An example here: [Syntax of LIKE in PreparedStatement](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1018043232.20073.102.camel%40inspiron.cramers).

Comment: It works, but ether single quotes or double ones need to be removed. 'POLYGON((%s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s))'

Comment: I have tested! It is so.

Comment: So, it is as you said? Should I remove the single quotes?

Comment: Yes, one pair of quotes must be removed.

Comment: Ok. I'm glad that it worked and thanks for correction ;-) Good luck.